# OpenTelemetry exporter endpoint is not working in docker

Tags: open-telemetry

I have .NET Core Web API Server and OpenTelemetry collector as docker container. But with my docker-compose, any event from web server does not be sent to otel collector container while it is working using "http://localhost:4318" as otlp endpoint without docker.

My `docker-compose.yml`:

```
version: "2.1"
services:
  web:
    build:
      context: ..
      dockerfile: ./MyWebServer/Dockerfile
    container_name: web
    networks:
      - test_net
    ports:
      - "8080:80"
  otel:
    image: "otel/opentelemetry-collector:latest"
    container_name: otel
    command: ["--config=/etc/otel-collector-config.yml"]
    volumes:
      - ./OpenTelemetry/otel-collector-config.yml:/etc/otel-collector-config.yml
    networks:
      test_net:
        ipv4_address: 172.23.10.4
    ports:
      - "4318:4318"
networks:
  test_net:
    ipam:
      config:
        - subnet: 172.23.0.0/16
```

My `Program.cs`:

```
using System.Diagnostics;
using OpenTelemetry.Resources;
using OpenTelemetry.Trace;

const string serviceName = "MyWebServer";
const string serviceVersion = "1.0.0";

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
builder.Services.AddControllers();

builder.Services.AddOpenTelemetryTracing(tracerProviderBuilder =>
{
    tracerProviderBuilder
        .AddOtlpExporter(opt =>
        {
            opt.Endpoint = new Uri("http://172.23.10.4:4318");
            opt.Protocol = OtlpExportProtocol.HttpProtobuf;
        })
        .AddSource(serviceName)
        .SetResourceBuilder(
            ResourceBuilder.CreateDefault()
                .AddService(serviceName: serviceName, serviceVersion: serviceVersion))
        .AddHttpClientInstrumentation()
        .AddAspNetCoreInstrumentation()
        .AddSqlClientInstrumentation();
});

var app = builder.Build();

app.UseRouting();
app.UseEndpoints(endpoints => { endpoints.MapControllers(); });

app.Run();
```

Comment: Pls provide reproducible example, e. g. used otel-collector-config.yml,  dockerfile,...

Answer (score 1):

You dont need to use IPaddress here. you can use service name and docker will resolve it automatically for you.

```
opt.Endpoint = new Uri("http://172.23.10.4:4318");
```

so in your case it should be

```
opt.Endpoint = new Uri("http://otel:4318");
```

Comment: Should not it be the container name? I see that in this case both are the same.